# Spark streaming and kafka integration

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I'm using kafka and spark streaming for a project programmed in python. I want to send data from kafka producer to my streaming program. It's working smoothly when i execute the following command with the dependencies specified:

./spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.1.0 ./kafkastreaming.py

Is there any way where i can specify the dependencies and run the streaming code directly(i.e. without using spark-submit or with using spark-submit but not specifying the dependencies.)

I tried specifying the dependencies in the spark-defaults.conf in the conf dir of spark.
The specified dependencies were:
1.org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.1.0
2.org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly:2.1.1

NOTE - I referred to spark streaming guide using netcat from
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html
and it worked without using spark-submit command hence i want to know if i can do the same with kafka and spark streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Provide your additional dependencies into the **"jars"** folder of your spark distribution. stop and start spark again. This way, dependencies wil be resolved at runtime without adding any additional option in your command line

Comment: Hi! I added the dependency "spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11-2.1.0.jar" and "spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.10-2.1.1.jar" to "jars" folder of spark and executed spark-submit without the "--packages" option, it gives an error saying that it can't find those dependencies.